# Show action bar when hovering a div with a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i'm looking for a solution but it's hard to understand and i've no examples :(

Imagine i've a div which contains an highchart graph. When hovering this div, i'd like to show an action bar in the bottom with an overlay.
Before launching a custom dev, is there a jQuery plugin to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try something like this : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsTjX/4/)

This custom code is not very difficult. It binds two event and toggle the action menu:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myChart").bind({
        //event mouse hover
        mouseenter:function(){
            $(".actionMenu").slideDown();
        },
        //event mouse out
        mouseleave:function(){
            $(".actionMenu").slideUp();
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: thanks. I now it's not difficult, but working with a plugins ca maybe avoid wasting time :)

Answer (score 0):

i did a little modification to have multiple items (@cana code)

http://jsfiddle.net/qsTjX/29/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myChart").hover(
        function(e){
            $(this).next('.actionMenu').stop().slideDown();
        },
        function(e) {
            $(this).next('.actionMenu').stop().slideUp();
        }
    );
});
```